# How to get rid of FoxfitReader Document classification?

Tags: pdf, file-format, foxitreader

I installed Foxfit Document Viewer as I was trying it as an open source replacement for acrobat. I didn't really liked it so i got rid entirely of it. But there is a problem. Now any PDF file is Classified in Nautilus and other applications as a "FoxfitReader document". How do I get it to show as PDF files?

[This is what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA5Ou.png)
[Same as here in Evolution Mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISn3X.png)

Comment: Welcome to ask Ubuntu, please give the standard info Ubuntu version desktop environment (e.g. gnome or KDE). This helps us figure out how to help

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and Gnome 42.1

Comment: Ubuntu has a built-in PDF viewer, what do you need Acrobat for? Also, there is no fairly recent version of Acrobat for Linux - are you using a Windows one via WINE?

Comment: Well, I found useful the Adobe document cloud. I'm not using Acrobat through WINE as Adobe online services doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution by looking at `.local/share/mime/application` and deleting the `pdf.xml` and `ppdf.xml`. In the `.local/share/mime` directory, open `types` file and delete the Foxfit entry.